# getting command line arguements from optparser without using argv[x]

Tags: python, command-line-interface

so I'm trying to add functionality to a script which takes a variable number of command-line arguments, for example:

```
python -u hi.py ENTRY_METHOD /onefolder/ /twofolder/ a b c d e f
```

or

```
python -u hi.py ENTRY_METHOD /onefolder/ /twofolder/ a b c d
```

So the argv[s] are like so:

```
argv[0] == hi.py
argv[1] == ENTRY_METHOD
argv[2] == /onefolder/
argv[3] == /twofolder/
argv[4] == a
argv[5] == b
argv[6] == c
argv[7] == d
```

I need to use optparser (i know, old and deprecated).

I would like to make this work like so:

```
python -u hi.py ENTRY_METHOD -q /onefolder/ /twofolder/ a b c d
```

where -q does what I need to but doesn't effect the argv[s] value (ie. d will continue to equal argv[7] and because it's a variable number -q wouldn't count as argv[8] given the command:

```
python -u hi.py ENTRY_METHOD /onefolder/ /twofolder/ a b c d -q
```

does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can accomplish this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "where -q does what I need to"?  If you can clarify  what you're asking for, you may get more useful solutions

Comment: You should take a look at `argparse`, or `click` if you're willing to look at third-party cli libraries.

Comment: What have you tried? This is what `optparse` is designed to do: to extract options and return the remaining arguments. If you really need the remaining arguments replace the contents of `sys.argv`, then that's just a simple assignment.

Comment: Are you already using `optparse` (in which case, why do the indices into `sys.argv` matter?), or do you want to introduce `optparse` (in which case the indices *won't* matter)?

Comment: Both `optparse` (undocumented) and `argparse` (more or less documented) have a function that will parse known arguments and return the remaining unparsed arguments as a list, which would target your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reset sys.argv:

```
argv = list(sys.argv)
argv.remove("-q")
sys.argv = tuple(argv)
```

Comment: does this also remove "-q" such that argv is decremented by 1?

It seems to treat it as a "none" type (either way) and throws a 'Nonetype' object is not iterable

Comment: @Hans Sorry, my error. You can use list.remove like that. I edited it.